# Отсутствие библиотек Runtime на сервере Websphere

Tags: java, maven, gwt, зависимости, websphere

Здравствуйте, я задал этот вопрос на англоязычном портале, но пока он безмолвствует. Посему с надеждой обращаюсь к вам.
Есть приложение на **GWT** в котором я использую **CMIS connector** для того чтобы закачивать документы в **SharePoint**. Я без проблем запускаю приложение и тестирую сервис в **Classic Dev Mode (Еклипс)** и на **Томкат 7**. В обоих случаях используется **JDK Oracle 7**. Когда я пытаюсь загрузить приложения в **Websphere 8.5.5**(с собственным **IBM JDK**) приложение не запускается со следующей ошибкой:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                     java.lang.VerifyError
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:224)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:61)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:129)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:152)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:431)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:288)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1111)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
            at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:211)
            at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:372)
            at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
            at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
            at my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.getJaxbContext(XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:245)
            at my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl$1.makeObject(XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:72)
            at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
            at my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.parse(XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:158)
            at my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.parse(XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:128)
            at my.package.core.server.license.LicenseProvider.readFromXml(LicenseProvider.java:155)
            at my.package.core.server.license.LicenseProvider.get(LicenseProvider.java:123)
            at my.package.core.server.license.LicenseProvider.get(LicenseProvider.java:50)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
            at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
            at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
            at my.package.core.server.services.i18n.I18NConfigurationServiceImpl.getLanguages(I18NConfigurationServiceImpl.java:53)
            at my.package.core.server.schema.SchemaLoaderImpl.scanPackage(SchemaLoaderImpl.java:150)
            at my.package.core.server.schema.SchemaLoaderImpl.loadSchema(SchemaLoaderImpl.java:204)
            at my.package.core.server.schema.SchemaLoaderImpl.loadSchema(SchemaLoaderImpl.java:195)
            at my.package.core.server.schema.CustomSchemaLoaderImpl.loadSchema(CustomSchemaLoaderImpl.java:71)
            at my.package.core.server.services.SchemaServiceImpl.getSchema(SchemaServiceImpl.java:144)
            at my.package.core.server.SchemaDBInitialize.start(SchemaDBInitialize.java:91)
            at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:70)
            at my.package.core.server.LsServer.start(LsServer.java:161)
            at my.package.core.server.AppInitializer.contextInitialized(AppInitializer.java:210)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1732)
```

Это не полный `stacktrace` - я опускаю логи от

> "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer..."

Эта строка:

> my.package.core.server.xml.impl.XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.getJaxbContext
>   (XmlDataBindingServiceJAXBImpl.java:245)

вызывает `JAXBContext` из `javax.xml.bind` и в конце концов останавливается на:

> com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl

из `dependency jaxb-impl`, которая является частью `chemistry-opencmis-client-impl`.

Это мои **CMIS dependencies** из **POM** файла:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
        <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-websphere</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

В поисках решения, я, в том числе, компилировал проект на **IBM JDK**.

Я думаю, что скорее всего в **Runtime** не хватает каких-то библиотек, но не понятно каких именно (как я уже сказал, у меня не было подобных проблем в **Tomcat**). Я был бы признателен за любую помощь или намек, потому что уже долгое время я мучаюсь с этой проблемой.

Comment: На SO вопрос по этому поводу уже несколько раз задавался, ответы легко найти поиском. Проблема в том, что у Websphere собственная версия JAXB конфликтующая с вашей.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Я прочитал много ответов за последние два дня, но если вы имеете в виду какой-то конкретный ответ пожалуйста дайте ссылку. Я использую "parent last" в Websphere именно для того, чтобы мои библиотеки были приоритезированны и класс `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl` я нахожу в Еклипсе то есть скорее всего это именно та имплементация, которая упокованна Maven-oм. Я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Я с Websphere не сталкивался уже более десятка лет, так что в этом из меня плохой советчик. Но сравнительно недавно имел дело с подобным конфликтом и решил вопрос исключением проблемной зависимости из проекта. Как раз с помощью `<exclusion>`. Можно попробовать копнуть в эту сторону, если приоритет не помог.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  В конце концов проблему мы решили схожим образом - все зависимости связанные с парсингом Xml (конкретнее - xercesimpl, xml-apis, geronimo-stax-api, xml-beans, activation) мы добавили в maven профиль для "нормальной" сборки, а в профиль для WebSphere мы поставили их с scope `provided`. Вы можете скопировать ваш комментарий в ответ и я его приму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Websphere собственная версия JAXB конфликтующая с вашей. Вам нужно с помощью `<exclusion>` исключить JAXB из зависимостей.